# Include libmcrypt in a C program linux

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I want to compile and run a `C` program that uses AES encryption system for sending of a message. I have downloaded

i have downloaded `libmcrypt` from here
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/
i assume it works on linux

i created a 'crypt.c' in the root folder of the archive :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "lib/mcrypt.c"

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

i created a 'crypt.sh' that would compile and run the program :

```
rm crypt.exe; gcc -o crypt.exe crypt.c -l "lib"; ./crypt.exe $1 $2;
```

and i get this error

```
In file included from lib/mcrypt.c:43:0,
                 from crypt.c:5:
lib/libdefs.h:80:3: error: #error "Cannot find a 32 bit integer in your system, sorry."
 # error "Cannot find a 32 bit integer in your system, sorry."
   ^
lib/libdefs.h:88:3: error: #error "Cannot find a 16 bit integer in your system, sorry."
 # error "Cannot find a 16 bit integer in your system, sorry."
   ^
lib/libdefs.h:94:3: error: #error "Cannot find an 8 bit char in your system, sorry."
 # error "Cannot find an 8 bit char in your system, sorry."
   ^
lib/libdefs.h:101:4: error: #error "Neither memmove nor bcopy exists on your system."
 #  error "Neither memmove nor bcopy exists on your system."
    ^
In file included from lib/mcrypt.c:47:0,
                 from crypt.c:5:
lib/mcrypt_internal.h:30:2: error: unknown type name ‘byte’
  byte *akey;
  ^
lib/mcrypt_internal.h:32:2: error: unknown type name ‘byte’
  byte *abuf; /* holds the mode's internal buffers */
  ^
lib/mcrypt_internal.h:35:2: error: unknown type name ‘byte’
  byte *keyword_given;
  ^
In file included from crypt.c:5:0:
lib/mcrypt.c: In function ‘internal_init_mcrypt’:
lib/mcrypt.c:95:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
  free(sizes);
  ^
lib/mcrypt.c:100:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memmove’ [enabled by default]
  memmove(td->keyword_given, key, lenofkey);
  ^
lib/mcrypt.c: In function ‘mcrypt_free’:
lib/mcrypt.c:257:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
  free(ptr);
  ^
crypt.sh: 1: crypt.sh: ./crypt.exe: not found
```

now the main question is :

How do i import a `LIBRARY` in `ANSI C`?

I need to encrypt some data in `C` and send it over the internet with `curl` (library that i mannaged to use it)

This is how i managed to include the `curl` library in my program :

`rm curlate.exe; gcc -o curlate.exe curlate.c -l "curl"; ./curlate.exe $1 $2;`

where `curl` is a folder near the `start.sh` and it contains only `.h` files.